# Can you reuse one of the buffers in the merge method of Spark Aggregators?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

The [merge](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Aggregator.html#merge-BUF-BUF-) method of the [Apache Spark Aggregator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Aggregator.html) class takes two buffers and combines them into one. Can I reuse one of the buffers (possibly modifying it) instead of creating a new one to be returned?

I noticed this in the documentation of the [reduce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Aggregator.html#reduce-BUF-IN-) method:

> For performance, the function may modify b and return it instead of
> constructing new object for b.

but there's no similar message on *merge*. I also found [this example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d1a333d554ad1da59bca277641f9e7d26247a0c6/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/SimpleTypedAggregator.scala#L138) in the Spark code which returns one of the buffers instead of creating a new one, so I'm assuming that (at least) this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merge is called by ComplexTypeAggregateExpression which implements [TypedImperativeAggregate](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/interfaces.scala#L522) or by [udaf.ScalaAggregator](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/aggregate/udaf.scala#L487) which is wrapped in a TypedImperativeAggregate when calling toColumn.

The scaladoc for that merge shows:

```
Merges an input aggregation object into aggregation buffer object and returns a new buffer object. For performance, the function may do in-place merge and return it instead of constructing new buffer object.
This is typically called when doing PartialMerge or Final mode aggregation.
Params:
buffer – the aggregation buffer object used to store the aggregation result.
input – an input aggregation object. Input aggregation object can be produced by de-serializing the partial aggregate's output from Mapper side.
```

i.e. the 1st param is the current partition's buffer.

The actual caller of that merge function is also in TypedImperativeAggregate:

```scala
final override def merge(buffer: InternalRow, inputBuffer: InternalRow): Unit = {
  val bufferObject = getBufferObject(buffer)
  // The inputBuffer stores serialized aggregation buffer object produced by partial aggregate
  val inputObject = deserialize(inputBuffer.getBinary(inputAggBufferOffset))
  buffer(mutableAggBufferOffset) = merge(bufferObject, inputObject)
}
```

i.e. the buffer you return from merge will be re-used as this partitions buffer.

You are able to re-use either the left or right objects as you see fit.